# ValueError: No data provided for "dense_input"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using following simple code to load a csv using tensorflow and perform modeling using keras...

Unable to figure this error!

```
import tensorflow as tf

train_dataset_fp = tf.keras.utils.get_file(fname=file_path, origin=URL)
columns = ["X","Y"]

features = columns[:-1]
labels = columns[-1]

batch_size = 32

train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    train_dataset_fp,
    batch_size,
    column_names = columns,
    label_name= labels,
    num_epochs=1
)

data_iterator = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

X_train, Y_train = data_iterator.get_next()

from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=[len(X_train)]),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=batch_size)
```

While rest of the code is working fine, i am unable to figure why i am getting dense input error.

The same code works flawlesly if using pandas, i am trying to remove dependencies on other libraries therefore using tensorflow components, but seems to be failing.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                30        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 11        
=================================================================
Total params: 41
Trainable params: 41
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhinavasrivastava/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 267, in standardize_input_data
    for x in names
  File "/Users/abhinavasrivastava/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 267, in <listcomp>
    for x in names
KeyError: 'dense_input'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_linear_keras.py", line 47, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1000, callbacks=[tb], steps_per_epoch=batch_size)
  File "/Users/abhinavasrivastava/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1536, in fit
    validation_split=validation_split)
  File "/Users/abhinavasrivastava/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 992, in _standardize_user_data
    class_weight, batch_size)
  File "/Users/abhinavasrivastava/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1117, in _standardize_weights
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/Users/abhinavasrivastava/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 271, in standardize_input_data
    'for each key in: ' + str(names))
ValueError: No data provided for "dense_input". Need data for each key in: ['dense_input']
```

Answer (score 2):

The error `No data provided for "dense_input"` means that Keras did not get input data at all or not in the expected format, i.e., in the form of an array which in Python means a numpy array.

Supposing everything else works fine it should help to simply add a line to convert X_train and Y_train:

```
import numpy as np
X_train = np.array(X_train)
Y_train = np.array(Y_train)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use salutations on Stack Overflow. These serve no purpose to the answer, and are thus noise. Additionally, overtly linking to your own website might be perceived as spam and deleted as such. Please refrain from doing this in the future. Do keep up the answering work!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using `tf.Dataset` to fit into Keras model. Keras model is not taking the data correct because you did not indicate the feature name of the feature cols in the dataset. To fix this, you need to explicitly feed the feature name `name=features` in the `model.fit` function:

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=batch_size, name=features)
```